# How do I get the size of a response attachment in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, wsdl, attachment, soapui

I'm performing a series of file uploads and downloads through a WSDL defined interface in SoapUI (not Pro). The built-in assertions to verify these attachments are insufficient.  I've found some Groovy code that allows me to get the size of the upload attachment.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.RequestFileAttachment

def uploadsize = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Upload File (200KB)").testRequest.getAttachmentAt(0).getSize()
```

I'm looking for comparable code to get the size of the download attachment.  The HTTP headers specify that the content type is "multipart/related" and UTF-8.  The attachment itself is "Content-Type: application/octet-stream \n Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"

I've tried the following snippet of code but it doesn't give me the size of the attachment, just the size of the response.

```
def downloadsize = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Download File (200KB) (Logged)").testRequest.response.contentAsString.size()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the documentation for the SoapUI Groovy classes is labyrinthine at best, I used introspection to find out what kind of class I was working with:

```
log.info testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Download File (200KB) (Logged)").testRequest.class.name
log.info testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Download File (200KB) (Logged)").testRequest.response.class.name
```

which yields:

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequest
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.WsdlMimeMessageResponse
```

Now one doesn't need to guess which class to look up.

The resulting code for attachment size is:

```
def downloadsize = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Download File (200KB) (Logged)").testRequest.response.getAttachments()[0].getSize()
```

Comment: If you just want the current test step, you can avoid specifying the test step's name and use 
`def downloadsize =  context.testCase.getTestStepAt(context.getCurrentStepIndex()).testRequest.response.getAttachments()[0].getSize()` instead. This way your script is more versatile and robust when it comes to refactoring.